# JSON Error: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of why?

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am getting the following error with andoroid trying to return data from PHP

> Error: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text
>   must start with '[' at character 1 of

PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php 
#
header('Content-type: application/json');
print json_encode(array('name' => 'john'));

#
?>
```

THE RETURN:

> 09-07 08:49:04.740: INFO/result(704): {"name":"john"}

please help me

Comment: Can you show what the output of the PHP script is?

Comment: what is the code you used to parse this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to parse an object with the Array parser instead of the JSON object parser

Comment: not true: JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
   for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Log.i("log_tag", "id: " + json_data.getString("username")
      + ", name: " + json_data.getString("name")
      + ", sex: " + json_data.getString("a_email"));
    // Get an output to the screen
    returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: Can you code format that and put it in the original question please?  Also which line do you get the error on.  There could be an Array as of the indexes of the Array which would cause that error.

Comment: just to be sure "9-07 08:49:04.740: INFO/result(704):" isn't really in the output, right??

Answer (score 0):

Here in this code mention above( JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);).result is not a JSONArray and so you need to convert the result into JsonArray by adding "["+result+"]" or you need to create JSONObject.

One answer  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("["+result+"]");

other answer  JSONObject  jobject=new JSONObject(result);